# How can I remove the padding of a blazor page?

Tags: blazor

I'm learning Blazor hybrid and I couldn't find a way to remove the padding on the main page.
Here is my code

```
<div class="box1">    
</div>

<style>
    body{
        background-color:brown;
    }

   .box1{
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
       background-color:yellow;
    }
</style>
```

And the result is as follows:
[image]

I would like to have the yellow box at the top left corner.

I tried to change in the MainLayout.razor the content like so:

```
<main>
 <article class="content px-0">
        @Body
 </article>
</main>
```

setting px to 0

I also tried to remove completely the class "content".
This removed the top padding but not the left one as shown below:
[image]

Has someone an idea how to achieve my goal?

Comment: Open inspector window in your browser and check what's happening.

Comment: Look in `MainLayout.razor.css`

Comment: Hi kiner_shah. I wonder how it is possible to open inspector window if one is working on a Blazor hybrid application? Is there a way to do it because the ui is not displayed in a browser in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the cause. Note the use of !important you probably have been battling with.

MainLayout.razor.css

```css
@media (min-width: 641px) { 

...
    .top-row, article {
       padding-left: 2rem !important;
       padding-right: 1.5rem !important;
    }
}
```